# Example for morphisms injective on ring but not dominant

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have proved that a dominant morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of varieties(in fact, integral schemes) induces an injection on regular functions $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(X)$.
If someone have an example to show the converse is not true in general(non-affine case)?

Comment: Consider a constant morphism $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$.